# jQuery .append() causing the target div to be cloned each time

Tags: javascript, jquery

first time poster, apologies for any mistakes.

I'm a newbie to web dev, and am learning javascript at the moment.

I'm building a little tool to help me in my day job, which involves quoting prices for foam cushions. I'm building a calculator that takes inputs for length width height qty and foam type, then generates prices. That part is working as planned.

You can see the entire code here: http://codepen.io/nicholasnbg/pen/VmGeVv

I'm running in to trouble in trying to save the prices into a table.

The first cushion I save appends as normal, but when I then generate a second cushion price, and click the button to save/append it to the table, it also saves the details for the first cushion again, as well as the new 2nd cushion.

so my table then looks like:

-cushion1

-cushion1

-cushion2

-cushion1

-cushion2

-cushion3

When I just want it to look like:

-cushion1

-cushion2

-cushion3

Here is the function I've made:

```
$('#savePrice').click(function() {
      console.log("price saved");
      if (lastCalculated) {
        var code = "<div class='row'> <div class='col-md-2 qtyL'>" + qty + " </div>  <div class='col-md-4 dimL'>" + width * 1000 + " x " + length * 1000 + " x " + height * 1000 + "</div>  <div class='col-md-2 eachPrice'>" + "$" + cushionPrice + "</div>  <div class='col-md-2 totalLinePrice'>" + "$" + (cushionPrice * qty).toFixed(2) + "</div> </div>    ";

        $(".priceList").append(code);

        clearInputs();
      };
```

Comment: The function you posted is missing a part...

Comment: And where is that `append` part?

Comment: Just like @MateuszWoźniak already pointed out, the code in your post is missing the rest of the `click` callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested the event listeners. You should almost always avoid nesting event handlers. Think of event handlers as code that is executed when an event occurs (The event, in this case, is a click). When a user clicks on '#go' something should be done. When a user clicks on '#savePrice' something else needs to be done. Both are independent. If you need to check if '#go' was clicked before '#savePrice' is clicked then do something like I did below (check if lastCalculated has a value) though there are many ways you may check this.

I suggest something like:

```
var lastCalculated; // keep record of the last calculation

$("#go").click(function() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value / 1000;
    var length = document.getElementById("length").value / 1000;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value / 1000;
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var disc = document.getElementById("disc").value;
    var dRate = 1 - (disc / 100);
    var cubic = width * length * height;
    console.log(cubic);
    // $('#cubic').html('cubic: ' + cubic);
    var e = document.getElementById("foamDD");
    var foamType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(foamType);
    var price;
    for (x = 0; x < foams.length; x++) {
      if (foamType === foams[x].name) {
        price = foams[x].price;
      }

    }
    var cushionPrice = (price * cubic * dRate).toFixed(2);

    lastCalculated = { // keep this calculation in memory
      qty: qty,
      width: width,
      length: length,
      height: height,
      cushionPrice: cushionPrice
    };

    $('#price').html('$' + cushionPrice + ' each');
    $('#total').html('Total Price = $' + (cushionPrice * qty).toFixed(2));
  });

$('#savePrice').click(function() { // notice this event handler is no longer nested inside the #go click handler
      if(lastCalculated) {
        var code = "<div class='row'> <div class='col-md-2 qtyL'>" + lastCalculated.qty + " </div>  <div class='col-md-4 dimL'>" + lastCalculated.width * 1000 + " x " + lastCalculated.length * 1000 + " x " + lastCalculated.height * 1000 + "</div>  <div class='col-md-2 eachPrice'>" + "$" + lastCalculated.cushionPrice + "</div>  <div class='col-md-2 totalLinePrice'>" + "$" + (lastCalculated.cushionPrice * lastCalculated.qty).toFixed(2) + "</div> </div>    ";

        $(".priceList").append(code);

        lastCalculated = null; // remove the calculation from memory, it is no longer needed
      }

      clearInputs();
    });
```

Comment: Ah this worked perfectly, I see where the issue was coming from now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's how your js file have to look like..
I suggest you to change your approach and avoid using global vars whenever you can.

You added a listener into another listener, so every click results in another instantiation of the second listener.. so you had 1 more listener for click in "save" everytime you had a click on "go".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var med = {
    name: "23-130",
    price: 625
};
var cushionPrice = 0;
var medFirm = {
    name: '29-200',
    price: 878
};
var foams = [med, medFirm];

$("#go").click(function() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value / 1000;
    var length = document.getElementById("length").value / 1000;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value / 1000;
    var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var disc = document.getElementById("disc").value;
    var dRate = 1 - (disc / 100);
    var cubic = width * length * height;
    console.log(cubic);
    // $('#cubic').html('cubic: ' + cubic);
    var e = document.getElementById("foamDD");
    var foamType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(foamType);
    var price;
    for (x = 0; x < foams.length; x++) {
        if (foamType === foams[x].name) {
            price = foams[x].price;
        }

    }
    cushionPrice = (price * cubic * dRate).toFixed(2);
    $('#price').html('$' + cushionPrice + ' each');
    $('#total').html('Total Price = $' + (cushionPrice * qty).toFixed(2));



});

$('#savePrice').click(function() {
        console.log("price saved");
        var code = "<div class='row'> <div class='col-md-2 qtyL'>" + qty + " </div>    <div class='col-md-4 dimL'>" + width * 1000 + " x " + length * 1000 + " x " + height * 1000 + "</div>    <div class='col-md-2 eachPrice'>" + "$" + cushionPrice + "</div>    <div class='col-md-2 totalLinePrice'>" + "$" + (cushionPrice * qty).toFixed(2) + "</div> </div>        ";

        $(".priceList").append(code);

        clearInputs();
    });
});

function clearInputs() {
    console.log('inputs cleared');

    document.getElementById("width").value = '';
    document.getElementById("length").value = '';
    document.getElementById("height").value = '';
    document.getElementById("qty").value = '';
    document.getElementById("disc").value = '';
    width = 0;
    length = 0;
    height = 0;
    qty = 0;
    disc = 0;
    dRate = 0;
    price = 0
    cushionPrice = 0;

};
```

Comment: Hi Luca, thanks for the help.

Only problem now is the html code 'var code' , which is now outside of the $("#go").click() handler, is using a bunch of variables contained in the $("#go").click(function(){});

What is the best way of accessing these variables if I should be avoiding global variables?

Comment: You should build a class.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes . Anyway.. it's ok to use global if you are learnig.. step by step :) ..if you need them global, set them global

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that on each `#go` click you define new event listener on `#savePrice`, that's why you've got duplicated records.

The easiest fix you can implement is to add one line to your function:

```
$('#savePrice').unbind('click').click(function() {
   ...
});
```

Anyway, there might be another issue, if you click `#go` button few times and `#savePrice` after, you will end up with few same records. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

With every click on the button "Go" you are initializing new click handler for $('#savePrice') selector. The quick solution is just to unbind the click event before initialization.
Ex:

```
$('#savePrice').unbind("click").click(function() {...});
```